# MySQL many-many JSON aggregation merging duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, json, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble returning a JSON representation of a many-many join. My plan was to encode the columns returned using the following JSON format

```json
{
  "dog": [
    "duke"
  ],
  "location": [
    "home",
    "scotland"
  ]
}
```

This format would handle duplicate keys by aggregating the results in a JSON array, howver all of my attempts at aggregating this structure so far have just removed duplicates, so the arrays only ever have a single element.

### Tables

Here is a simplified table structure I've made for the purposes of explaining this query.

#### media

```
| media_id | sha256                                                           | filepath             |
| 1        | 33327AD02AD09523C66668C7674748701104CE7A9976BC3ED8BA836C74443DBC | /photos/cat.jpeg     |
| 2        | 323b5e69e72ba980cd4accbdbb59c5061f28acc7c0963fee893c9a40db929070 | /photos/dog.jpeg     |
| 3        | B986620404660DCA7B3DEC4EFB2DE80C0548AB0DE243B6D59DA445DE2841E474 | /photos/dog2.jpeg    |
| 4        | 1be439dd87cd87087a425c760d6d8edc484f126b5447beb2203d21e09e2a8f11 | /photos/balloon.jpeg |
```

#### media_metdata_labels_has_media (for many-many joins)

```
| media_metadata_labels_label_id | media_media_id |
| 1                              | 1              |
| 2                              | 1              |
| 3                              | 1              |
| 1                              | 2              |
| 4                              | 2              |
| 5                              | 2              |
| 1                              | 3              |
| 6                              | 3              |
| 7                              | 3              |
| 8                              | 4              |
| 9                              | 4              |
```

#### media_metadata_labels

```
| label_id | label_key | label_value |
| 2        | cat       | lily        |
| 4        | dog       | duke        |
| 6        | dog       | rex         |
| 1        | pet size  | small       |
| 3        | location  | home        |
| 7        | location  | park        |
| 8        | location  | scotland    |
| 9        | location  | sky         |
| 5        | location  | studio      |
```

### My current attempt

My latest attempt at querying this data uses `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` with two arguments, the first is just an empty JSON object and the second is an invalid JSON document. It's invalid because there are duplicate keys, but I was hoping that `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` would merge them. It turns out `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` will only merge duplicates if they're not in the same JSON argument.

For example, this won't merge two keys

```sql
SET @key_one = '{}';
SET @key_two = '{"location": ["home"], "location": ["scotland"]}';
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@key_one, @key_two);

-- returns {"location": ["scotland"]}
```

but this will

```sql
SET @key_one = '{"location": ["home"] }';
SET @key_two = '{"location": ["scotland"]}';
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@key_one, @key_two);

-- returns {"location": ["home", "scotland"]}
```

So anyway, here's my current attempt

```sql
SELECT
  m.media_id,
  m.filepath,
  JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(
    '{}',
    CAST(
      CONCAT(
        '{',
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', l.label_key, '":["', l.label_value, '"]')),
        '}'
      )
      AS JSON)
  )
  as labels
FROM media AS m
LEFT JOIN media_metadata_labels_has_media AS lm ON lm.media_media_id = m.media_id
LEFT JOIN media_metadata_labels AS l ON l.label_id = lm.media_metadata_labels_label_id
GROUP BY m.media_id, m.filepath
-- HAVING JSON_CONTAINS(labels, '"location"', CONCAT('$.', '"home"')); -- this would let me filter on labels one they're in the correct JSON format
```

After trying different combinations of `JSON_MERGE`, `JSON_OBJECTAGG`, `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` this still leaves me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Since posting this question I've started using mariadb instead of oracle MySQL. The function below should work for MySQL too, but in case it doesn't then any changes required will likely be small syntax fixes.

I solved this by creating a custom aggregation function

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION JSON_LABELAGG (
  json_key TEXT,
  json_value TEXT
) RETURNS JSON
BEGIN
  DECLARE complete_json JSON DEFAULT '{}';
  DECLARE current_jsonpath TEXT;
  DECLARE current_jsonpath_value_type TEXT;
  DECLARE current_jsonpath_value JSON;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND RETURN complete_json;

  main_loop: LOOP
    FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
    SET current_jsonpath = CONCAT('$.', json_key); -- the jsonpath to our json_key
    SET current_jsonpath_value_type = JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(complete_json, current_jsonpath)); -- the json object type at the current path
    SET current_jsonpath_value = JSON_QUERY(complete_json, current_jsonpath); -- the json value at the current path

    -- if this is the first label value with this key then place it in a new array
    IF (ISNULL(current_jsonpath_value_type)) THEN
          SET complete_json = JSON_INSERT(complete_json, current_jsonpath, JSON_ARRAY(json_value));
      ITERATE main_loop;
      END IF;

    -- confirm that an array is at this jsonpath, otherwise that's an exception
    CASE current_jsonpath_value_type
      WHEN 'ARRAY' THEN
        -- check if our json_value is already within the array and don't push a duplicate if it is
        IF (ISNULL(JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(complete_json, current_jsonpath), "one", json_value))) THEN
          SET complete_json = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(complete_json, current_jsonpath, json_value);
        END IF;
        ITERATE main_loop;
      ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Expected JSON label object to be an array';
    END CASE;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN complete_json;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and editing my query to use it

```
SELECT
  m.media_id,
  m.filepath,
  JSON_LABELAGG(l.label_key, l.label_value) as labels
FROM media AS m
LEFT JOIN media_metadata_labels_has_media AS lm ON lm.media_media_id = m.media_id
LEFT JOIN media_metadata_labels AS l ON l.label_id = lm.media_metadata_labels_label_id
GROUP BY m.media_id, m.filepath
```